# What is the gcc equivilant for Xlc '-qnotwolinkis' compiler option?

Tags: gcc, porting, xlc

I am currently porting my compiler from AIX XLC compiler to GCC compiler on AIX.

I want to know if there is an GCC equivalent compiler option available for the '-[qnotwolinkis](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPSQF_9.0.0/com.ibm.xlcpp111.aix.doc/compiler_ref/opt_twolink.html)'(XLC).

Comment: In [IBM XL C/C++ for AIX](https://ibm.co/2NgKBcT), the default is `-qnotwolink`, which will link all static constructors defined anywhere in the object (.o) and library (.a) files. I believe this is the default for GCC on AIX too. With XL, you can optionally supply `-qtwolink` so that the static constructors defined in the object files are invoked, but not the ones in the library files. Are you looking for a GCC equivalent for `-qtwolink`? Also, if you are moving off of XL due to lack of language standard support, IBM just released [V16.1](https://ibm.co/2NfJ9Yh) with full support for C++14.